# How do I seperate my game and game engine into seprate projects?

Tags: java, architecture

I am trying to separate my game from the game engine, both written in Java. Currently, they are in two separate packages, but I would like to separate them into different projects.

A main method in "Project B" starts a game loop in "Project A". This loop needs to call back to methods in "Project B". What is the best method to achieve this, without "Project A" being aware of the specific implementation of "Project B"?

---

"Project A" (Engine - Library):

```
public class Engine {

    public static void start() {
        init();
        // Call Game.getInstance().init() from Project B.

        while (true) {
            input();
            // Call Game.getInstance().input() from Project B.

            update();
            // Call Game.getInstance().update() from Project B.

            render();
            // Call Game.getInstance().render() from Project B.
        }

        cleanUp();
    }

}
```

"Project B" (Game - Executable)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Engine.start();
    }

}

public class Game {

    private static Game instance = new Game();

    private Game() {}

    public static Game getInstance()
        return instance;

    public void init()
        // Do Stuff

    public void input()
        // Do Stuff

    public void update()
        // Do Stuff

    public void render()
        // Do Stuff

}
```

Comment: What language do you use? This may be relevant for specific implementation. And also _why_ do you need it, this may help give better answers.

Comment: I am using Java (I have edited the question to show this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your engine in super classes. Have a game, an entity, etc.

Then to make a new game, extend the game class which has your game loop. To add an entity, extend the entity class.

So the game class would have a generic game loop. Your game would extend that game class and override the parts you need. The game class can be coded to handle the entity class. So you extend the entity class and add them to your extended game class

Comment: I have attempted this however, how can I call this subclass of game in project B from project A, without changing and recompiling the line 'import ProjectB.GameSubClass;' in project A for each game?

Comment: Write engine in project A. Turn it into jar. Then include jar in project B

Comment: I have implemented a class called 'Game' in project A and the 'Game' class in project B now extends it.

The 'Engine' class from project A calls the 'Game' class in project A, instead its subclass 'Game' in project B.

How do I correct this, while maintaining a singleton?

Comment: The engine should never make any reference to the game

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by having the game be a dll and the engine being the executable.

There are side benefits to this as well.  If your main menu / matchmaker etc screens are in the engine and only actual game sessions use the game dll, you end up completely tearing down the resources used by the game between matches.

This can help with memory fragmentation and can also solve the class of bugs where state isn't properly reset between matches.  These bugs can be pretty nasty and hard to track down.